# IMapViewDelegate method not getting called "UIView MarkerInfoWindow(MapView mv,Marker m)"

Tags: ios, google-maps, xamarin.ios

On Xamarin iOS I have a map which has markers. I want to have a custom Info View but the problem is that the delegate method "UIView MarkerInfoWindow(MapView mv,Marker m)" for the IMapViewDelegate  doesn't get called somehow. I have no idea whats the problem.

I have uploaded one simple repo demonstrating this problem at
https://github.com/aproram/Xamarin-GMapsDelegate-IssueDemo

Any idea why this is happening and the method doesn't get called ?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to modify `GoogleMapsDelegate`

```
class GoogleMapsDelegate : MapViewDelegate
{
     public override UIView MarkerInfoWindow(MapView mapView, Marker marker)
    {
        UIView toBeView = new UIView();
        //toBeView.AddSubview(iv);
        toBeView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;
        toBeView.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
        return toBeView;
    }
}
```